# mysql subquery for find duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following 3 scripts to find
unwanted duplicate entries:

note: I try to add a unique-index on SchafID:LammDate which is not allowed by mysql when it violates existing roles.
and: In duplicate entries also has different data in other fields, i need to ask the operator which of them is the good one, befor delete them.

query 1: create a table with duplicate entries

```
 create table duplikate_lammen 
 SELECT `fldSchafID`, `fldLammDate`, count(*) cnt  
 FROM `tblLammen`  
 group by `fldSchafID`,`fldLammDate`
 having cnt > 1
```

result table:

```
ID      Date                    cnt     
901     2011-02-17 00:00:00     2
1330    2011-10-07 00:00:00     2
etc etc
```

query 2:

```
select fldSchafID, max(fldLammDate) date 
from duplikate_lammen group by `fldSchafID`
```

query 3: (use copy paste for each entry)

```
SELECT fldID, fldLammID, fldLammDate, fldCrDate 
FROM `tblLammen` 
WHERE `fldSchafID` = 901 
AND `fldLammDate`= '2011-02-17 00:00:00'
Order BY `fldCrDate` Limit 1
```

result: (the newerst of duplicates)

```
fldID   fldSchafID  fldLammDate     fldCrDate 
1441    901         2011-02-17      2011-03-21 09:35:38
```

My question:
Is there a way to do this with single query and without auxiliary table, using sql only?

Comment: I think I can see a way, but it would be helpful if you could post examples of your data 'before' and 'after'.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: it is mainly a subquery question ... how to put the 3 given querys in a single one. With a good solution i can execute a delete order for duplicate later.